# How to make a set of parallel of undefined number of requests using rxJava in Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, zip-operator

Currently I have a service that returns that returns a list of parameters. if there are 4 parameters I need to perform one request per parameter to the same endpoint using the each of the parameter. After that I need to save the list of results of  all the request into a collection. If I don't know how many request do I have to perform, **What rxJava operator I need to use and how should I use it??** .
Take into account that I don't need to wait for the answer of the first request to perform the second one and ....

I have seen that the zip operator allow me to perform parallel request but I have to know the number of request to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I implemented it this way:

```java
public Subscription getElementsByStage(List <String> requiredStages) {
    List < Observable <ElementsResponse>> observables = new ArrayList < > ();
    for (String stage: requiredStages) {
        ElementsRequest request = buildElementRequest(stage);
        observables.add(request).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()));
    }
    Observable zippedObservables = Observable.zip(observables, this::arrangeElementsByStage);
    return zippedObservables
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber <HashMap<Stage,Element>>() {
           .....
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` to create `Observable` for each `parameter` and execute them in parallel as in

```
Observable.fromArray(parameters)
           .flatMap(val -> Observable.just(val)
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .map(request -> doApiCall(request))
            )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> log(response));
```

Comment: your call `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` will have not effect changing threads, should it be `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to change the `Thread` in the `Observer`?

Comment: Yea, Thanks my bad